# Interpreting Impulse Response Function

Tags: time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am trying to estimate a forward guidance shock on the expected path of the future federal funds rates and industrial production of manufacturing and construction. I built my SVAR model using Smith and Becker's (2014) method, and now am trying to generate impulse response functions, but I don't quite understand how to intepret my findings. The first five plots are responses of the expected future federal funds rate at the third, fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh horizon to a forward guidance shock, and the last two plots are impulses responses of industrial production of construction and manufacturing to a forward guidance shock. It makes sense to me that the first five graphs are around zero because the interest rates are at the ZLB. I don't quite understand how the last two plots make sense, if the y axis is in the units of the variable of interest, why are the numbers so small? My industrial production data runs in the 90-100s range. How should I go about interpreting this or fixing the issue, if that is what's causing the weird y-axis. [image]

Comment: Hi: Here is the paper that one would need read in order  to understand the method. Unfortunately, you have to belong to the AEA to be able to obtain it. https://www.aeaweb.org/articles/pdf/doi/10.1257/0002828053828446

Comment: Perhaps Economics Stack Exchange is a better place for this question? It seems some macroeconomic expertise is required to answer the questions about intepretation.